# 'Directory is not owned by current user', can't install python-dev using pip3 on mac yosemite

Tags: python, macos

I'm trying to work through this guide and I need to install python-dev and pyautogui http://automatetheboringstuff.com/chapter18/

when I try to install python-dev using pip3 I get the following error message
https://i.stack.imgur.com/FSAOW.jpg

Is something wrong with my version of pip3 or python3?

Comment: First, how did you install your Python 3? From a Python.org installer, Homebrew, manually from source, etc.?

Comment: Second, please put the error message into your question, not off-site. And as text, not as a screenshot.

Answer (score 0):

First, you read the Linux directions, instead of the OS X directions. There is generally no such thing as `python-dev` on Macs.

Second, you didn't read them correctly. Even if you're on Linux, you install `python-dev` with `apt-get` or `yum` or `urpmi` or some similar system-packages tool, not with `pip`.

Third, you didn't read the output correctly. You're ignoring the big red errors telling you that there's no such package as `python-dev`, and focusing on the dull olive warnings. (Although if you really do want to deal with those warnings, note that they tell you right in the text what to do.)

Just do what the documentation says:

> On OS X, run `sudo pip3 install pyobjc-framework-Quartz`, `sudo pip3 install pyobjc-core`, and then `sudo pip3 install pyobjc`.

If you've installed your Python 3 in a way that doesn't require `sudo` (e.g., through [Homebrew](http://brew.sh/), or by checking the checkbox I forget the name of in the Python.org installer), leave the `sudo` off.

Anyway, I won't promise that those instructions will work for your setup (especially if you've gone off-script earlier in the process), but I will promise that ignoring the instructions and just typing random commands from somewhere else on the page is not going to work.

Comment: username:~ username$ pip3 install pyobj-framework-Quartz
Collecting pyobj-framework-Quartz
  Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement pyobj-framework-Quartz (from versions: )
  No matching distribution found for pyobj-framework-Quartz

Comment: @Grant: The package is called `pyobjc-framework-Quartz`, not `pyobj-framework-Quartz`. Again, that's right there in the instructions; just copy and paste it.

Comment: As a side note, I don't know why the instructions don't just tell you to install `pyobjc`. That will automatically grab `pyobjc-core`, `pyobjc-framework-Quartz`, and the 30-odd other packages that are part of PyObjC.